# What is this spaceship-like fruit?

Tags: identification, fruits

The fruit is around 3in in diameter. Zone 7, private yard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pomegranate. Commonly cultivated in the Mediterranean. Should grow quite a bit more than the 3 inches diameter you are observing, and become a bit redder when ripe... although I guess depends on the variety.

Rather than a spaceship looks more like royalty if you turn it with the crown facing upwards :).

Comment: Or the stolen Swedish crown jewels!

Comment: They do! :D :D :D

Answer (score 15):

Looks like pomegranate, or *[Punica granatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomegranate)*. Pretty common fruit, you can even find it in the supermarket.

Comment: Is that an immature pomegranate or a different variety? It's a different color and the fruit is much smaller relative to the bud (?) than the pomegranates I'm used to.

Comment: @divibisan, there are [yellow](http://fruitspecies.blogspot.com/2007/08/pomegranate_14.html) varieties, but I think you are right that they are still immature (judging from the large crowns).